# Record only chat in Google Meet

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-meet

If I record during Google Meet meeting, two files are created in Google Drive - one containing the video, the other one containing transcript of chat. Is it possible to record in a such way that only the chat transcript is saved? (Of course, I can simply delete the video file - however waiting until this large file created just to delete it and keep the much smaller file seems kind of redundant.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Google doesn't support this.  I wanted to do the same but the answer I got from google was that they don't support saving the chat transcript.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't support this functionality.

One way to achieve this is by using an extension like Tactiq.io which will save the transcription of your Google Meet meeting, and now also saves the chat log too.

Quicker than waiting for google's recording to process.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using Tactiq Chrome Extension. It [saves chat](https://help.tactiq.io/en/articles/5446753-save-google-meet-chat) and transcripts of Google Meet meetings. Tactiq is available on the Chrome Web Store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tactiq-for-google-meet-tr/fggkaccpbmombhnjkjokndojfgagejfb/).